# Integral of momentum with respect to time

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, kinematics, momentum

What is the outcome if any of such an integral? I am asking about the outcome other than the position of the object; specifically if this somehow pertains to energy used.

\begin{equation*}
 \int_a^b mv(t)d t
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 5):

Since as:

$$v(t)=\frac{dx(t)}{dt}$$
$$\implies v(t)dt=dx(t)$$
So:

$$\int_{x(a)}^{x(b)}mdx(t)$$

Assuming $m$ to be constant, then:
$$\int_a^b mv(t)dt=\int_{x(a)}^{x(b)}mdx(t)=m[x(b)-x(a)]$$
So it's a mass times a displacement.

Comment: I am explicitly looking for answers pertaining to the correlation to energy in the system, or the lack thereof. Simply saying that the result "is mass times a displacement" is as ambiguous as saying (in a different example, and assuming the asking person doesn't know what a moment is, or what work is) "it is force times a distance".

Answer (score 0):

The energy used, understood as the integral of force with respect to displacement (i.e. work) corresponds to the force (instead of momentum) applied during a certain time.

Example: Accelerating steadily a particle, you can choose to invest a certain force over a certain length, or alternatively to invest a certain force during a certain time. In the first case, force times displacement equals energy (work),
$$ W = \int{Fds}$$
in the second case, force times time equals momentum,
$$p = \int{Fdt}$$